# Add new font with @font-face doesn't work

Tags: html, css, layout, fonts

is there any error in the follow code ?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'raveFire';
    src: url('ravefire.eot');
    src: local('raveFire'), url('ravefire.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

this code is into the file "style.css" and, the files ravefire.ttf and ravefire.eot are in the same folder than "style.css" ...

Ive tried use this new font-family in span, style, class, etc ... I also tried several browsers...

please, any help ?

Comment: Did you run the font(assuming its a legit font) through fontsquirrel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using font-face quite a bit recently and I've not seen the "local" reference, try it without, i.e.:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'raveFire';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('ravefire.eot') format('eot'), url('ravefire.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Make sure your fonts are in the same folder as the page, or use absolute paths to them.

Comment: Could be wrong since i've only played with a bit a while back, but hey, if memory serves right, then the local is for IE fix.

Comment: Or it used to be anyway, perhaps by now there will be some new method and fixes.

Comment: I already fix the problems ... It was just a mistake in the font's file name ...

THE CODE WORKS FINE !!!!

thnx by the answers !